# Any $ \mathbb Z^n < A < \mathbb Q^n$ has rank $n$.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups

In [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group), it says that:

> For any intermediate group $\mathbb Z^n < A < \mathbb Q^n$, $A$ has rank $n$.

If I understand this statement correctly, it says that if $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q^n$ that contains $\mathbb Z^n$, then the largest free abelian group contained in $A$ has rank $n$.

I was wondering if there is a reference for this result.

Comment: You should include to your post the definition of rank here, since there are [other ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_group).

Comment: Imo no reference is needed: the proof is on that Wikipedia page, just before the statement.